# Insert a new column into a pandas pivot_table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

After formatting and groupby-ing my DataFrame, I have created the following pivot_table which shows the number count of M and F for a given credential:

```
Gender            F         M
Credential                   
AA            105.0     117.0
AU            870.0     249.0
CNA          6309.0    5276.0
```

What I would like to do next is insert another column which has the ratio of F to M for a given credential. Eg:

```
Gender            F         M    Ratio
Credential                       
AA            105.0     117.0    0.8974
AU            870.0     249.0    3.4939
CNA          6309.0    5276.0    1.1957
```

I have been encountering the issue where the new column can't be added because it wasn't already a category.

```
TypeError: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category
```

Which I believe does make sense as there isn't a "Gender" called "Ratio" and that isn't what I am wanting. Does anyone have any suggestions? I thought it would be as simple as:

```
df["Ratio"] = df["F"] / df["M"]
```

But evidently not.

EDIT:

If not entering a new column to the original DataFrame, perhaps extracting the data from the original DataFrame and creating a new DataFrame with that Ratio column?

EDIT2:

Here are the steps to reproduce:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Credential': np.random.choice(['AA', 'AU', 'CNA'], 100), 
    'Gender': np.random.choice(['F', 'M'], 100), 
    'Counts': np.random.randn(100)
    })
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].astype('category')
dfNew = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Counts', index='Credential', columns="Gender")
dfNew["Ratio"] = dfNew["F"] / dfNew["M"]
```

EDIT3 (Workaround Code):

Here is the step to workaround the error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Credential': np.random.choice(['AA', 'AU', 'CNA'], 100), 
    'Gender': np.random.choice(['F', 'M'], 100), 
    'Counts': np.random.randn(100)
    })
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].astype('category')
dfNew = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Counts', index='Credential', columns="Gender")

# Changing from categoricals
dfNew.columns = dfNew.columns.tolist()

dfNew["Ratio"] = dfNew["F"] / dfNew["M"]
```

Comment: Pandas version: 0.21.0

Comment: As of pandas 1.3.4, this works as OP intended.